# Show class name in C# Properties Grid

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I'm creating a properties grid using C#.NET for my AutoCAD plugin. This plugin checks each entity in an AutoCAD drawing for XRecord data and if it finds any, attempts to deserialize it into a class. All of that is working so now I want to show a stored object's properties in my form's properties grid. Here is the class who's information I want to show

```
public class SerializeTest
    {
        #region class variables
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public SerializeTest(int passedX, int passedY)
        {
            this.X = passedX;
            this.Y = passedY;
        }

        private SerializeTest()
        {

        }

        #endregion
    }
```

And here's what it looks like in my form when I click the AutoCAD entity that is storing it as an XRecord

[image]

I want to add the object's class type (in this case SerializeTest) before the other properties. How would I customize the properties grid like that?

[image]

Specifically, I want it to look like this except with the class field at the top not the bottom

Comment: So why is replacing the "Misc" shown now, with the text "Class SerializeTest" not a solution to your question?

Comment: Because I dont want to have to add [Category("SerializeTest")] to each variable of every class that I might want to store. Plus I may need to add other custom properties later and would like to know how

Comment: Well then I guess I had better delete my answer, and you had better add to your question that you don't want to use the default convention of using attributes to annotate the members of your classes.

Comment: @NickG You need to create a custom [Property Descriptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.aspx), and make the `SerializeTest` implements [ICustomTypeDescriptor interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx).Keywords: **PropertyDescriptor** and or **ICustomTypeDescriptor**.